# Why doesn't work if we calculate NN's error like target - output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a Neural Network, where I calculate the delta of output layer like:

```
delta_L = Output(i) - L;
```

And it works well. But if I change it, to:

```
delta_L = L - Output(i);
```

Then it doesn't work. (Despite Andrew Ng's course recommends the second one)

Why?

Comment: It will be best if you at least give us the source of your information and use a better notation, what is L? What are you interested in? The error in respect to some weight, the delta as in the "delta rule", or the difference between target value and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a 3-layer nn with 2 hidden layers, with standard notations the nn  is shown below:

[image]

with and the cost function as sum (or average) square loss over the training dataset (for regression, with continuous valued output)

[image]

with the back-propagation expressions:

[image]

As you can see, `delta_L` is `output[i] - L` in your notation, assuming that `L=y` is your actual value of the output variable and `a=output[i]` is the nn prediction, this expression matches with the one from Andrew Ng's course, refer to [this](https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2018/05/31/8626/) article for more details. We can show the same for classification / cross-entropy loss too.

Comment: I said it wrong, please forgive me. So, L is the output layer.